# Sum of open and closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces, sumset

Let $A,B$ subsets of a normed space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ and $A+B=\{a+b\mid a\in A,\, b\in B\}$

I need help with the next proofs, I can't figure how to begin the proofs:

(a) If $A,B$ open then $A+B$ open

(b) If $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid x>0 \:\&\: xy\ge1\},\: Y=\{(0,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid y\in \mathbb{R}\}$ then $A,Y$ closed on $\mathbb{R}^2$
(Maybe prove it using sequences?)

(c)$A+Y=\{(x,y) + (0,z) \mid (x,y) \in A,\: (0,z)\in Y\} = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x>0\}$ is not closed

For the (a) question I was thinking if I can see it as $$\bigcup a+B \quad \forall a\in A$$ but I don't know how to prove $$a+B=\{a+b\mid b \in B\}$$ is an open set (if it's true it's an open set).

For the (c) question I should prove that $A+Y$ is open or I should prove that given a sequence in $A+Y$ it doesn't converge to a point of $A+Y$ ?

Comment: What help do you need exactly? Is it with general concepts, understanding the question, a step in a proof, how to begin?

Comment: How to begin would be perfect, I'm a bit confused

Comment: What confuses you? It would be ideal if you added that to the body of your question

Comment: Start with problem a). What does it mean for $A$ and $B$ to be open? What would have to be true for $A+B$ to be open? Can I take those properties of $A$ and $B$ and use them to prove $A+B$ is open? Spend some time on that and then tell us what you tried and why you think you are at an impasse.

Comment: @JohnDouma I just edited the question with some ideas, I'm a bit confused in which way should I prove them, (using sequences, using the definitions, etc)

Comment: For b) it's a good idea to use sequences. You can take a convergent sequence and show that the limit is a point that belongs to the same set. 

For c) it's similar but not exactly what you wrote: you need to prove that there is **some** sequence in $A+Y$ which converges to a limit and that the limit is a point outside of $A+Y$. This does not need to happen to every sequence on $A+Y$, just one of them is enough to break the property of being closed.

Comment: Your idea for a) is a good one. To show that $a+B$ is open consider an open ball around $b\in B$. You know one exists because $B$ is open. When you add $a$ to all of the vectors in the open ball around $b$ you get an open ball around $a+b$. In fact, you're just saying that if you translate an open ball by a vector $a$, you get an open ball that has been moved.

Comment: @frl93, for a) you can prove that for a fixed $a\in X$ the map $X\rightarrow X$ given by $x\mapsto a+x$ is a homeomorphism. Then $a+B$ is the image of $B$ under this map and hence is open

Comment: Hint for (a): I assume that you can prove that any "open ball" $B(x,r) = \{y\,|\,y\in X, \|y-x\|< r\}$ is open. How is $a+B(x,r)$ related to $B(x+a,r)$?

Comment: Since B is open, $\forall p\in B\: ,Br(p) \subset B$
for some r > 0. Is it true $Br(p + a) = Br(p) + \{a\}$? If true then $Br(p) + \{a\} \subset B + \{a\}$ no? Then $B+\{a\}$ open

Comment: @frl93 If $v$ is in the open ball of radius $r$ around $b\in B$ then $|a+b - (a+v)|=|b-v|\lt r$ so $a+v$ is in the open ball of radius $r$ around $a+b$.

Comment: Keep in mind for part (c) that open and closed are not opposites! You need to show that A+Y is not closed; i.e. there exists some sequence in A+Y that converges to a point not in A+Y. (Just one sequence suffices. This can't possibly hold for every sequence in A+Y. For example, constant sequences in A+Y all converge to points in A+Y.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would begin the proofs:

- a) Let $w$ be an arbitrary point of $A+B$. Then $w$ has the form $a+b$ with $a$ in $A$ and $b$ in $B$. $A+B$ is open if each of its points has a neighbourhood contained entirely in $A+B$. We know that there should be neighbourhoods $N_a$ and $N_b$ of $a$ and $b$ contained entirely in $A$ and in $B$, respectively, because these two sets are open. Can these neighbourhoods be used to find a neighbourhood of $w$ contained in $A+B$?
- b) I'll start with $A$. Let $\{(x_n, y_n)\}$ be a sequence of points in $A$, and further suppose that it converges to some point $p=(x,y)$ on the plane. Can we show that $p$ is contained in $A$ using what we know about the sequence? We know that $x_ny_n\ge1$ and that $x_n$ is positive for every $n$.
- c) Some geometric intuition may point to an example of a sequence in the set with a limit outside of the set: is some "border" of the set not included in the set's definition? Try to describe a sequence of points with $x>0$ approaching one of those points in the border.

Comment: For (b): Since $(Xn,Yn) \rightarrow (x,y)$ then $(Xn)\rightarrow x \: \& \: (Yn)\rightarrow y$ and $(Xn)>0 \forall n$ then $x$ must be positive right? Because $(Xn)\rightarrow x \:\&\: (Yn)\rightarrow y$ then $(XnYn)\rightarrow xy$ since properties of convergent sequences, and $XnYn \ge 1$ then $xy$ must be $\ge 1$ am I right?

Comment: @frl93 you are right, except that in your first sentence, in the limit, $x$ could also be $0$. i.e. from your first sentence you get $x\ge0$.