# $X$ open, $X+Y$ also open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, sumset

Question: Let:

$$X,Y \subset\mathbb{R}$$

and:

$$X+Y= \{x + y : x\in X, y \in Y\} $$

Show that if $X$ is open, then $X+Y$ is also open.

I'm not sure where to start can someone help me it would be appreciated.

Comment: $X+Y=\cup_{y \in Y} (X+y)$ and $X+y$ is open for each $y$.

Comment: Start with the definition of  $X+Y$ being open in terms of containing an open neighborhood of any point that belongs to it.

Comment: See also: [Sum of open and closed sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1536362). (It is the same question - however, in the context of arbitrary normed spaces rather than just real line.)

Answer (score 3):

Take $z\in X+Y$. There are $x$ and $y$ such that $z=x+y$. As $X$ is open, there is $r>0$ such that $(x-r,x+r) \subset X$. We then have:
 $$ (z-r, z+r)= (x+y-r, x+y+r) = (x-r,x+r)+\{y\} \subset X+Y.$$

Answer (score 3):

Let bet $x\in X$, as $X$ is open you know that exists $\epsilon$ such that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)\subset X$. Then you have $(x+y-\epsilon, x+y+\epsilon)\subset X+Y$ for all $y\in Y$.